Mathematical expression of Fourier transform used in numpy.fft.fft
I am trying to use numpy.fft.fft to perform discrete Fourier transformation. Normally, Fourier transformation is defined as,

My question is : does numpy.fft.fft also use this formula ?
If one writes the exponent inside the above integral in terms of sine and cosine and K(s) is taken as an even function, the imaginary part of the above integral  vanishes. But in my case, I am using an even function and still the imaginary part comes out to be non-vanishing. That's why I am asking the above question.
I am giving a code example here taking K(s) = cos(s).
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [4]: import cmath

In [5]: s = np.linspace(-10,10,10000)

In [6]: s
Out[6]: 
array([-10.       ,  -9.9979998,  -9.9959996, ...,   9.9959996,
     9.9979998,  10.       ])

In [7]: f = np.cos(s)

In [8]: f_t = np.fft.fft(f)
 
In [9]: f_t.imag
Out[9]: 
array([ 0.        , -0.18989373, -0.56552844, ...,  4.58808084,
    0.56552844,  0.18989373])


Yes - after a fashion. Implicit in the FFT is that your finite range of data samples is tiled periodically on the infinite number line to compute. The imaginary part will only vanish if you and the FFT library that you are using agree on where w=0. Most FFTs have w=0 at the origin. I don't know what numpy does. When using FFTs to compute DFTs you have to be aware of their limitations - they are not quite the same thing. The edge discontinuity for an FFT where it wraps around can really hurt the answer. That said even functions should have nil imaginary components to within rounding errors.

check the source code for more information. Question is a bit out of context for stackoverflow as the question is not programming related. Maybe better ask this at DSP stackexchange

You need to give a minimal, reproducible example of what you are seeing if you want us to diagnose your issue for you

@Homer512 I have given a code sample in the question.

See here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19892/discrete-fourier-transform-of-even-function

No, the FFT is a fast algorithm to compute the DFT, which is not the same as the FT. The FT is explicitly written for continuous-domain signals. Read up on the DFT: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

If you look at the code you've written. np.fft.fft doesn't care at all of your vector s. You cannot justify your expectation that a DFT algorithm (as the FFT is) recognizes if a signal comes from an even or an odd function. Please remember that a DFT just maps N complex numbers in the time domain to N complex numbers in the frequency domain. The only valid expectation is, if the time sample x is made up of real numbers, Re(X) is symmetric wrt the 0 frequency,  while Im(X) is antisymmetric

I suggest that you make your array size a lot smaller! Try 8 for starters and then display the entire array and think carefully about the complex values. Also make your real limits +/- pi so that the cos() function will behave periodically at the boundaries.  I think the OP's problem is that his function is being interpreted according to the most common FFT convention where the very first array element of the array is the phase centre (rather than the middle of the array).  Or make the range eg. 0 - n*pi.

@gboffi FFT doesn't care about the input function but to within rounding errors it will result in a nearly pure real result for an even function and a nearly pure imaginary result for an odd function. The requirement for this to hold is that the signal presented to the FFT must have its origin must be in exactly the right place.  OP has put his origin half way along the array and chosen a range that is not a multiple of pi - both of these will cause him trouble.  Also useful to be aware that FFT of real data will produce a complex conjugate symmetric transform result.
